# List of medical terms

Tags: dataset, medical

Does anyone know where I might get my hands on a list of medical terms (diseases, etc.)? Diminutive forms are unnecessary. Crucially, the data cannot be dirty, and cannot contain words that are typically not used in a non-medical sense. The use of this list requires that false-positive identification of a medically relevant term be kept to a minimum. To this end it does not have to be exhaustive (precision vs recall).

I have found a number of lists on github. However ones like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glutanimate/wordlist-medicalterms-en/master/wordlist.txt) have common first names included (such as Jacob, Jack, Marcus, Robin, etc.), meaning that all such terms would have to be manually weeded out before it could be used.

Comment: Diseases and their diagnoses for example are standardized as ICD - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Statistical_Classification_of_Diseases_and_Related_Health_Problems. Refine the requirements. I guess you're looking for `English` but in Radiology and Pathology it is not uncommon that doctors use [Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) as the finding-description language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Health.gov data sets have diagnosis codes used by Medicare